# Transforming a nonlinear system to a linear system

Tags: transformation, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Suppose I have two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I wish to find values of parameters $a$ and $b$ such that I obtain the power law $y=ax^b$ which goes through the two given points. I can solve the nonlinear system
$$\begin{eqnarray}
y_1 &=& ax_1^b\\
y_2 &=& ax_2^b \end{eqnarray}$$

or I can take the log of both sides and obtain
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\ln(y_1) &=& \ln(a)+b\cdot\ln(x_1)\\
\ln(y_2) &=& \ln(a)+b\cdot\ln(x_2) \end{eqnarray}$$

a linear system which can be easily solved by using a direct solver for example and then I can obtain $a$ and $b$ easily. I can do the same for an exponential ($y = ae^{bx}$) and even a Gaussian $\left(y = ae^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-b}{c}\right)^2}\right)$.

My first question is, is this approach possible for the Lorentzian function ($y=\frac{a}{b+(x-c)^2}$)? What kind of a transformation would I do?

Does this technique have a name? Is there a general approach to this? Given an arbitrary function, is there a way to determine if such a method is possible or not? If yes, how do we determine the appropriate transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I suppose that you have three data points ($i=1,2,3)$ $$y_i=\frac{a}{b+(x_i-c)^2}$$ from which you want to extract parameters $a,b,c$.

If you compute the ratio $A_{12}=\frac{y_2}{y_1}$, $a$ is gone and you can extract $b$. you can do the same with $A_{13}=\frac{y_3}{y_1}$ and extract $b$ again. Write that these two values of $b$ are equal and you obtain a linear equation in $c$ which is easy to solve. Now, go backwards to get successively $b$ and $a$. After simplifications, you should then get

$$c=\frac{1}{2}\frac{{x_1}^2 {y_1} ({y_2}-{y_3})+{x_2}^2 {y_2}
   ({y_3}-{y_1})+{x_3}^2 {y_3} ({y_1}-{y_2})}{ {x_1}
   {y_1} ({y_2}-{y_3})+{x_2} {y_2}
   ({y_3}-{y_1})+{x_3} {y_3} ({y_1}-{y_2})}$$ $$b=\frac{{y_2} (c-{x_2})^2-{y_1} (c-{x_1})^2}{{y_1}-{y_2}}$$ $$a={y_1} \left(b+(c-{x_1})^2\right)$$

**Added later**

Since this is to be used for regression and since this model is nonlinear with respect to its parameters, linearization would provide reasonable starting guesses for the nonlinear regression.

So, let us start with $$y=\frac{a}{b+(x-c)^2}$$ and rewrite it as $$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{x^2-2cx+(b+c^2)}{a}=\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma$$ The quadratic regression based on points$(x_i,\frac{1}{y_i})$  will give $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. So, now $$a=\frac{1}{\alpha},b=\frac{4 \alpha  \gamma -\beta ^2}{4 \alpha ^2},c=-\frac{\beta }{2 \alpha }$$

But again, the values are just starting guesses since in the linearized model you minimize $$SSQ_1=\sum_{i=1}^N \Big(\frac{1}{y_i^{exp}}-\frac{1}{y_i^{calc}}\Big)^2$$ while, since the $y_i$ are the measured values, you must minimize $$SSQ_2=\sum_{i=1}^N \Big({y_i^{exp}}-{y_i^{calc}}\Big)^2$$

**Illustrating example**

To illustrate this aspect, I generated data using $a=123.4,b=5.6,c=7.8$ for $x$ varying between $0$ and $20$ ($21$ data points) and the exact values of $y$ were randomly perturbed (relative change between $-10$% and $+10$%).

The linearization step leads to $\alpha=8.323492415\times 10^{-3}$,$\beta=-1.299834856\times 10^{-1}$,$\gamma=5.468572881\times 10^{-1}$ to which correspond $a=120.142$, $b=4.732$, $c=7.808$. These do not seem bad when compared to the values used for the generation of the data. However, for these values, the sum of squares is $45.118$ and the nonlinear regression ends with a sum of squares equal to $3.932$ that is to say **almost $12$ times smaller** and the final parameters are $a=125.559$, $b=5.998$, $c=7.799$. Big differences !

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I don't want to solve the 3x3 system using exact arithmetic. I want to change the nonlinear system to a linear 3x3 system so that I can use a numerically stable direct linear solver. This method is unstable if any of the $y_i$'s are too close or too far apart. +1 for solving the Lorentzian system though. Thanks.

Comment: If I may ask a question, is this the full problem or is it part of a nonlinear regression problem for which you have $N$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and you want to tune parameters $a,b,c$ ?

Comment: It is part of a much larger nonlinear regression problem. But this can also stand alone on its own. I have three points and I want to determine $a$, $b$, and $c$ so that the Lorentzian curve goes through those three points. If I solve the nonlinear system, I need iterative methods and a starting value. I am trying to see if I can transform it into a linear system and then use a direct linear solver without an initial value.

Comment: This was I was supposing. When you perform the regression, it must be on the model and not on any transformed. Then, in your case, the model is nonlinear. Linearization will give you reasonable estimates. I think I found what you can do. I shall edit my answer.